# SQL function to create a one-to-one match between two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to join 2 tables. Table_A has ~145k rows whereas Table_B has ~205k rows.

They have two columns in common (i.e. ISIN and date). However, when I execute this query:

```
SELECT A.*,
       B.column_name

FROM   Table_A
       JOIN
       Table_B ON A.date = B.date

WHERE  A.isin = B.isin
```

I get a table with more than 147k rows. How is it possible? Shouldn't it return a table with at most ~145k rows?

Comment: nope, if there exists duplicate records for the same  date and isin you will get 2 or more rows per join

Comment: Dont know your table structure but joining using date is not good practise, If possible join using integer values in your table .
On why the number of rows is more than you expected, There may be duplicate records in your table which needs to be filtered out as well.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one row per table A, then use `outer apply`:

```
SELECT A.*,
       B.column_name
FROM Table_A a OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) b.*
      FROM Table_B b
      WHERE A.date = B.date AND A.isin = B.isin
      ORDER BY ?  -- you can specify *which* row you want when there are duplicates
     ) b;
```

`OUTER APPLY` implements a lateral join.  The `TOP (1)` ensures that at most one row is returned.  The `OUTER` (as opposed to `CROSS`) ensures that nothing is filtered out.  In this case, you could also phrase it as a correlated subquery.

All that said, your data does not seem to be what you really expect.  You should figure out where the duplicates are coming from.  The place to start is:

```
select b.date, b.isin, count(*)
from tableb b
group by b.date, b.isin
having count(*) >= 2;
```

This will show you the duplicates, so you can figure out what to do about them.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing indicates that, for some of the records in `Table_A`, there are several records in `Table_B` that satisfy the join conditions (equality on the  `(date, isin)` tuple).

To exhibit these records, you can do:

```
select B.date, B.isin
from Table_A
join Table_B on A.date = B.date and A.isin = B.isin
group by B.date, B.isin
having count(*) > 1
```

It's up to you to define how to handle those duplicates. For example:

- if the duplicates have different values in column `column_name`, then you can decide to pull out the maximum or minimum value
- or use another column to filter on the top or lower record within the duplicates
- if the duplicates are true duplicates, then you can use `select distinct` in a subquery to dedup them before joining
- ... other solutions are possible ...

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate possibilities is already discuss.

When millions of records are use in join then often due to poor `Cardianility Estimate`,
record return are not accurate.

For this just change join order,

```
SELECT A.*,
       B.column_name
FROM   Table_A
       JOIN
       Table_B ON A.isin = B.isin 
    and
A.date = B.date
```

Also create non clustered index on both table.

```
Create NonClustered index isin_date_table_A on Table_A(isin,date)include(*Table_A)
```

*Table_A= comma seperated list Table_A column which is require in resultset

```
Create NonClustered index isin_date_table_B on Table_B(isin,date)include(column_nameA)
```

`Update STATISTICS Table_A`

`Update STATISTICS Table_B`

Answer (score -1):

Keeping the DATE columns of both tables in the same format in the JOIN condition you should be getting the result as expected.

```
Select A.*, B.column_name
from Table_A
join Table_B on to_date(a.date,'DD-MON-YY')  = to_date(b.date,'DD-MON-YY') 
 where A.isin = B.isin
```